# How to visualize NHibernate hbm.xml files

Tags: nhibernate, hbm, visualize

Are there any tools or clever methods for me to I visualize the contents of NHibernation hbm.xml files?

I would like to load hbm files into a designer and see them as entities with relations

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few tools you might want to try.

[LLBLGen Pro](http://www.llblgen.com/defaultgeneric.aspx)

[Mindscape NHibernate Designer](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/blog/index.php/2010/08/10/announcing-the-mindscape-nhibernate-designer/)

[Visual NHibernate](http://www.slyce.com/)

Comment: Good answer, I was looking for a free version though.

Answer (score 3):

The hibernate tools plugin for Eclipse (Java) can visualize hibernate hbm.xml files.
It might work with some tweeks also for NHibernate hbm.xml files

http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html